# On FTP server delete file older than x days

Tags: ftp

I have access to FTP server, which has files stored on a xyz folder.
I need to delete files on xyz folder on remote FTP server which are more than x days old.
So far i have not arrived at any concrete solution.

Thanks,
Rosh

Comment: Your question is too broad. Do you need an script? are you using an specific PL ??

Comment: Ohh ya. Sorry. I need to do it in Unix Shell script. I am able to do get, put, move and delete. But finding files older than x days doesnt seem possible so far.